# Is it possible for a chat widget app to exists from two separate back-end servers?

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets

Im working on a school project, with as requirement to work with two backend servers. I have to make a chat widget app, with a widget on the website and a dashboard/chat for the agent. As I have to keep scalability in mind, I am making the structure before I start on the code. I have made two possible structures. While I think structure B is more practical and better, would structure A work? It's because my school prefers the way of A, but I am unsure if it would work.

Here are the structures I made:

[Structure A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuWsm.png)

[Structure B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOiwv.png)

As you see A has no general backend interface that connects the two backends together with the two front-ends. Therefore I see no other solution then to connect each front end to both backends each. Would the websockets still work and not overload?

Comment: [Another possible architecture](https://i.ibb.co/XLTXrxr/Chat-architecture.png)